# Angular ngresouce $update is not a function

Tags: angularjs, x-editable, ngresource

I am using angular xeditable to edit a field and update its value to the database but it isn't working. It keeps saying $update is not a function. Same with $save which is a POST.

Not sure if ng-repeat or xeditable is creating a scoping issue but the object being passed through the updateBusinessGoal function comes through with the value already changed and calling an update should be all that is needed.

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="goal in businessGoals.occupancyGoals | orderBy:'timeframe'">
     <td class="capitalize">{{goal.timeframe}}</td>
     <td>{{goal.current_value | number:0}}%</td>
     <td><a href="#" blur="sumbit" onaftersave='businessGoals.updateBusinessGoal(goal)' buttons="no" editable-text="goal.threshold">{{goal.threshold || 'empty'}}%</a></td>
</tr>
```

**JS**

```
businessGoals.updateBusinessGoal = function(goal){
    goal.$update({
        user_business_goal_id: goal.user_business_goal_id, 
        type: goal.type, 
        timeframe: goal.timeframe, 
        threshold: goal.threshold}
    );
}

return $resource(ENV.web_api_url + ENV.api_version + '/user/business_goals/:user_business_goal_id', {}, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT',
            params: {
                user_business_goal_id: '@user_business_goal_id',
                type: '@type',
                timeframe: '@timeframe',
                threshold: '@threshold'
            },
            headers: {
                "X-Auth-Token": $window.sessionStorage.token
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles upon this some day it is because this is bad syntax. It should be as easy as:

```
    businessGoals.updateBusinessGoal = function(goal){
        ServiceName.update(goal);
    );
}
```